# PInvokeStackBalance keeps being detected while the signature is OK

Tags: c#, c++, dll, pinvoke, managed

I have a little problem with my code. I've got a unmanaged C++ .dll that I want to use with a C# applaction.

The C++ function in the dll looks like this:

```
void EXPORT_API vSetLights(BYTE byLights)
{
    remote.SetLEDs(byLights);
}
```

The C# code looks like this:

```
    [DllImport("APlugin")]
    private static extern void vSetLights(byte byLights);
```

And I call the function like this:

```
        byte byLeds = 0x0;
        vSetLights(byLeds);
```

If I'm correct, the function signature is ok (Both return nothing and require a byte), but the PInvokeStackBalance keeps popping up. The application runs just fine after that, can I safely ifnore it or is there a fix?

Thanks,

Wesley

Comment: You need to provide the definition of EXPORT_API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your stack imbalance is probably caused by a difference in calling convention.  The default calling convention in `DllImport` is `WinApi` (which in turn defaults to `StdCall`).  It's likely that your C++ function is using the `Cdecl` calling convention.  You'll have to show us the definition of EXPORT_API in order to be sure.

The stack imbalance occurs because `StdCall` expects the called function to clean up the stack, and `Cdecl` expects the caller to clean up the stack.  So if a program that expects `StdCall` calls a `Cdecl` function, the stack doesn't get cleaned up.  Going the other way (`Cdecl` calling `StdCall`), the stack gets cleaned up twice.

You can change your `DllImport` to use `Cdecl`, like this:

`[DllImport("APlugin", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]`

Comment: EXPORT_API was indeed defined as __declspec(dllexport). Thanks for your answer, I learned a new thing today.